# Quickest way to generate a non-lazy list of numbers

Tags: clojure

I would like to find **the quickest way of generating a non-lazy list of numbers in clojure**. Currently I am using the following :

```
(doall (take 5000000 (iterate inc 5000000000)))
```

to generate a non-lazy list of numbers between 5 billion and 5.005 billion. Are there any quicker ways of doing this? Thanks

(p.s. I am aware that using lists to store sequences of numbers is sub-optimal. However I am using this as a benchmark for the **Shen.java** compiler)

Comment: You want a fast way to populate a slow data structure?

Comment: You can specify the start and end (and step) with `range`.

Comment: @AlisterLee : quickest way not fast. I knew that my approach was not the fastest approach to populate the list

Comment: @A.Webb : Thanks that seemed to be the fastest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `doall` works great. The only problem with your example is slow `iterate` function. You should use [range](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/range) instead of it:

```
(doall (range 5000000000 5005000000))
```

`range` is very fast. It's lazy, but it optimized and it generates numbers in chunks.

Here are benchmark results for `iterate` and `run` obtained using [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium):

```
user=> (quick-bench (doall (take 5000 (iterate inc 5000000))))
Evaluation count : 180 in 6 samples of 30 calls.
             Execution time mean : 3.175749 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.179449 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 2.428681 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 4.735748 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 14.758153 ns

user=> (quick-bench (doall (range 5000000 5005000)))
Evaluation count : 672 in 6 samples of 112 calls.
             Execution time mean : 1.253228 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 350.301594 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 845.026223 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 1.582950 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 14.758153 ns
```

As you can see, `range` is 2.5 times faster than `iterate` here.

On my PC it takes less then a second to generate all 5000000 numbers, but there are some tricks to make it work even faster.

For example, you may run the generation in the separate thread:

```
(let [numbers (range 5000000000 5005000000)]
  (future (dorun numbers))
  ...)
```

It won't make generation faster, but you'll be able to use your sequence immediately, before it'll be fully-realized.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. Shen.java was originally doing it in 4s whereas using clojure iterate was taking 7s, and I knew that I must have been doing the clojure version too slowly!

Comment: Strictly speeking, this answer is about generating and realizing a [**sequence**](http://clojure.org/sequences) not creating a [**list**](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Lists%20(IPersistentList)) as mentioned in the title. For a list you would need to do something like `(into '() (range 5000000000 5005000000))` (or `(into '() (range 5005000000 5000000000 -1))` to preserve order). But as I understand from the context that's not what you need here.

Comment: @PawełŁoziński Thanks yes I wanted list. Now clojure is taking about 4s which is on par with Shen.java.

Answer (score 0):

**doall** is usually what you need. But what do you mean by "quickest"? quickest in the context of performance or in the context of coding?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?